# Working with multiple OSGi bundles in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm currently learning how to work with OSGi, and I've got a little question that I can't seem to Google an answer for.

I'm trying to build a backend for my mobile app, and the backend will connect to several downstream nodes. Currently, this backend would initially support only my mobile app, but I plan to shift my web portal to use it as well.

Looking at how OSGi allows me to have modularize my code into several bundles, this is what I have in mind:

```
Backend
|--- osgi-mobile
|--- osgi-webportal
|--- osgi-downstreamnode1
|--- osgi-downstreamnode2
```

My problem lies with using/consuming the services from a downstream node bundle in a front-end bundle (e.g. **osgi-mobile** using/consuming services from **osgi-downstreamnode1**).

I'm currently building them in Eclipse Mars, and short of packaging the entire **osgi-downstreamnode1** bundle into a JAR, and importing it into the **osgi-mobile** bundle, I can't seem to figure out how to reference the bundles in Eclipse, as well as have the **osgi-mobile** bundle call the other bundles during runtime.

Comment: I do not understand the problem you face. Is it about offering and consuming services or about the packaging/deployment?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I guess it's a bit of both? Offering and consuming services would occur during runtime, whilst packaging and deployment would be during compilation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your help!

Through some trial and error, I have managed to get what I want via the **Export-Package** option and **Import-Package** option via **MANIFEST.MF**. I have run into another set of problems regarding the usage of third-party JARs, but I will post that in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider services already at development time. The tutorial referenced by hotzst should help. The basic of packaging is to create a bundle for each eclipse project. How to package them together then depends on where you want to deploy to.

I guess you currently use the eclipse PDE perspective to develop your application. I would not recommend this. If you know you do not develop Eclipse RCP applications then I would consider either plain Eclipse + maven or Bndtools. I got a lot of [tutorials for developing in plain eclipse and deploy into Apache Karaf](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials). For bndtools see [their tutorials](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html).

In any case you should expect a quite some learning curve. So some books may help like [OSGi in practice](http://njbartlett.name/osgibook.html) or [Apache Karaf Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/apache-karaf-cookbook).

Answer (score 0):

Services that can be used in OSGi are defined through an interface. The interface must be independent from the implementation bundle:
`bundleA` uses an implementation of `ServiceInterface` which is defined in `bundleBase`. Now `bundleA` has a dependency on `bundleBase`. Then you can add `bundeB` which implements the interface and thereby also has a dependency to `bundleBase`.

Through OSGi `bundleA` can now request service `ServiceInterface` and getting an instance of `bundleeB` without there being a direct dependency.
See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html